# How to Randomly select the dynamic value by clicking on the Radio button in a table -Not able to click on the Radio button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I have a table where i need to select the dynamic value everytime by clicking the radio button.

What i have tried:

I have first taken the list of radio button in the table :

```
List<WebElement> radiobuttonoptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//table[contains(@class,'mat-table cdk-table')])

[2]//following::span[contains(@class,'mat-radio-outer-circle')]"));
```

Then i take the list of the column - i have done this as i need to

select any of the options which starts with OPT in the OPTION column

This is the list:

```
 List<WebElement> section = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr/td[2]"));
```

Now if have got the text from the list of section  and check if the column

has the text :opt

```
 for(WebElement optinselection:optselection)
                {
                    
                     
{
Then i randomly go and click on the radio button
 {

                    Random random = new Random();
                    int index = random.nextInt(radiobuttonoptions.size());
                    radiobuttonoptions.get(index).click(); 

}
```

**My Problem is it is not clicking on the radio button .

Any input will be helpful.Any more information is required i can add.**

Can someone pls give inputs.

Comment: Is it possible to share the URL.

Comment: Yes you can update your question with screenshots of DOM.

Comment: added to the question but is not showing so this is my html for one vesel and have added the image

Comment: In the image there are 4 rows but The rows will increase as this is a dynamic table

Comment: if you print `radiobuttonoptions.size()` does it return the number of options or 0.

Comment: <span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator">

<span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple">

Comment: this is the html

Comment: yes it ir printing correctly it gives the option as 4

Comment: Can someone pls give inputs

Comment: I can see that `input` tags have `id`, try to collect those radio buttons with that. The xpath would be something like this. `//input[contains(@id,'mat-radio')]`.

Comment: pmadhu-  tried with what you said it is clicking but ny next question is when i click on the radio button once it is working but it is not coming out of the loop after clicking the button once any inputs on this

Comment: the scenario is after i click on the radio button i should go and clicking another button which is at the top of the page and it is not clicking the radio button with the vessel name starting with "VESEL"

Comment: Use a `break` statement after you click on the element. And I know you deleted a comment.

Comment: ok but it is not clicking on the Vessel with the name :VESEL instead goes and clicks on other names not with VESEl ANY inputs on this

Comment: and after putting a break it stops but is not going and clicking on the next button basically there are 2 issues: 1) It does not go and click on the next button after selecting the radio button 2)It selects a vessel which does not start with vessel name - vessel any inputs on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as discussed, xpath `//input[contains(@id,'mat-radio')]` worked to click on the radio buttons. if the `input` tag is within the `span`, then process should be somewhat like this.

```
radiobuttonoptions = driver.findElements("xpath for `span` that contains `VESE`")
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(radiobuttonoptions.size());
radiobuttonoptions[index].#find element by tag name `input` .click();
```

Comment: the span is preceding one for radio button and when i do that it takes either all the options or takes only 2 options it is the xpath which is problem now will deal with it thanks madhu for the help